# Swift 3: Stop it from converting [NSString] to [String]

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have this Objective-C method.

```
+ (NSArray<NSString *> *_Nullable)getValues;
```

which is converted in Swift to [String]
and must be passed to another Objective-C method in Swift, which looks in Objective-C like

```
- initWith:(NSArray<NSObject*> *_Nonnull)parameter;
```

So I have this Swift code :

```
let bla = C.getValues()
MyClass(bla)
```

This works flawlessly in Objective-C, but in Swift, it complains of course that [String] is no child of [NSObject], because it auto converted it from [NSString] to [String].
How can I stop Swift from doing that?

```
let bla = C.getValues() as! [NSString]
```

does not work, because in its infinite wisdom it converts it first from Objective-C to Swift Objects and then tries to convert it back to Objective-C Objects.
 Message here: 'NSObject' is not a subtype of 'String'.

PS: I know I can iterate over everything and make an array of converted copies, but there must be a better way than that:

```
var strings: [NSObject] = []
for string in bla! {
    strings.append(string as NSString)
}
```

Comment: `- initWith:(NSArray<NSString*>..` is not possible?

Comment: `let bla = [C getValues]` ??? Please rewrite question with correct syntax

Comment: @vadian No, it can take all childs of NSObject, not only NSString's.

Comment: Did you try `MyClass(bla as [NSObject])` ?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it comes down to the same compiler error message.

Comment: Strange, that compiles for me. – But `- initWith:(NSArray<NSObject*> *_Nullable)parameter;` is imported to Swift as `public init!(_ parameter: [NSObject]?)`, not as `public init!(with parameter: [NSObject]?)`, so `MyClass(with: bla)` cannot compile at all.

Comment: Sorry, when I followed the guideline: "Trim your code to the basics before you post" I made 2 errors:
- Yes, its 'MyClass(bla...'
- 2nd: '- initWith:(NSArray<NSString*> *_Nullable' must be '_Nonnull', then the Swift compiler complains more about input parameters (which may be converted to nil). If I do this: 'MyClass(bla! as [NSObject])' it works. What I did try was 'MyClass(bla as! [NSObject])'. Big Mistake.
Sorry for the errors in the post, but actually the wrong version helped me find the real one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `getValues` returning array can be null, you have to cast it to `[NSString]?`:

```
let bla = C.getValues() as [NSString]?
```

Then, since the init method requires a non-null parameter, you have to force unwrap `bla`:

```
MyClass(bla!)
```

or fall back to a default value:

```
MyClass(bla ?? [])
```

EXTRA:

`as!` is used for **down**casting. `C.getValues() as! [NSString]` is not equal to `(C.getValues() as [NSString]?)!`.

Comment: Nice answer, like it more than my solution :-)